# How to make custom function keycode shell?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

My old keyboard get some break, had physical damage. some keys not work.
Unfortunately, new small keyboard have no fuction keys(like <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>PgDown</kbd>, number pad, etc..) and no function+shortcut key for that. *(like <kbd>function</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> for <kbd>numpad 1</kbd>)*
so I want to **make execute press keycode shell** and set it to shortcut for use like number pad.*(like <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> for <kbd>numpad 1</kbd>)*
In many ask-ubuntu Q&A show me shift-key or remap-key information. but I don't want exactly change "Key" things. I need <kbd>J</kbd> key also.
is there any idea or command for "Press *any* keycode shell"?

I tried somes and think

1. xdotool seems just work in its own terminal (Not work in other application)

2. make toggle mod shell with xmodmap *(alternative plan)*

**#UPDATE#1**
Okay, here's the thing

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=122831

this link show xdotool window options

so I make shell file like this and it's perfect work in specific window

> win=$(xdotool search --onlyvisible --class blender|head -1)
>   
> xdotool key -c --window $win KP_Decimal

Now I have to find this work in active window not specific one :)